# Sonata Admin configureFormFields using custom form types

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have 2 entities:

**1. Question**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $test_field;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Option", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $options;
}
```

**2. Option**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Option
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="options")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $field_for_question_type_x;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $field_for_question_type_y;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $field_for_question_type_z;
}
```

Based on the `Question` type there needs to be different formType used which contains only some of the `Option` fields.

For example:

`Question` with `type = X` should have form with fields `$field_for_question_type_x`

`Question` with `type = Y` should have form with fields `$field_for_question_type_y`

etc.

I also have those different formTypes created so the question is how could I tell Sonata Admin `$formMapper` to add collection of such forms(based on Question entity type)?

Currently it looks like this:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $Question = $this->getSubject();

    $formMapper->add('test_field');

    if ($Question->getId()) {
        $formMapper->with('Options');

        switch ($Question->getType()) {
            case 'X':
                // Here I would need to add collection of \My\Bundle\Form\OptionXType()
                $formMapper->add('options', ????????);
                break;
            case 'Y':
                // Here I would need to add collection of \My\Bundle\Form\OptionYType()
                $formMapper->add('options', ????????);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What should be added to provide such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was quite simple:

```
->add('options', 'sonata_type_collection',
    array(),
    array(
        'edit' => 'inline',
        'inline' => 'table',
        'admin_code' => $type_based_admin_code # each has custom form configuration
    )
)
```